# Create users and groups Linux

Tags: linux, console

There is an other way to create users and groups without user and groupadd in console mode ?
I want to make new groups and new users without theses commands.

Thanks

Comment: you can edit the files manually (can't remember the names exactly, but should be in `/etc`) and that should **IN THEORY** work, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: I wanna do that to learn how does it's work.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files.
full info under the link:  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

Comment: This.  You'll still need to encrypt the password, etc.  Of course, one does have to ask "why"?

Comment: I've do that.
I've created users, encrypt pass and same for groups.

Comment: I'm happy answer was helpful to you!  
Could you accept it and resolve as the creator of the question?